# Why windows thinks that the internet is not connected?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

I have direct access to the internet. My OS is Windows 7.

I want to share internet to mobile devices via WIFi, but Windows shows that PC doesn't connected to internet. And I can't share wifi on this reason.

[image]

How can I change "No internet access" on "Internet access"?

Thanks for any kind of help.

!--------------------------------------------------------------

it's my ipconfig info:
[image]

Comment: Did you run the network troubleshooter. And I suggest connectify for internet sharing. Much better than windows in-built one

Comment: I try to use connectify, but it sharing only network, not internet.

Comment: "No internet access" usually means that you did not receive a proper DHCP address and you'll most likely have a so called `APIPA` address assigned to your network interface. These adresses start with `169.254`. Can you put the output of the command `ipconfig` (run this from the Command Prompt) in your question?

Comment: If this can helps. Done.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Sometimes Windows shows no internet access even if it has internet access. Can you access sites thru a browser? Do they open? Are you on a proxy?

Comment: Yes I have access to internet, but windows shows that I haven't. And I want to fix this. Because, it's a reason I can't share internet over WiFi. I don't use proxy, I use direct access (kind of VPN connection).